# Strange little bug: Simple real number replaced by Times[0.805`, \.00]

Tags: core-language

I had a bug in my code which I tracked down to the simple number 0.805.  So I looked at the FullForm of this number and I got

```
Times[0.805`, \.00]
```

It isn't a big deal, but I'm just curious what happened.

Here is more information.  On an input line

1. type: Times[0.805,.0
2. then enter one more character: 0

On the screen, instead of  Times[0.805,.00  , I see:  Times[0.805,

In other words, when I press the key for the last character (i.e., 0), three previous characters disappear.  Seems like a bug to  me.

3. Then on the same line I finally type: ] and press return. I get the output 0.805.  Looks fine.  But  when I type FullForm[%] I see everything I typed,  i.e.

Times[0.805`,.00]

Comment: Please read the [tag:bugs] info for its appropriate use.

Comment: What does the menu command Cell > Show Expression reveal about the cell containing the expression?  You may have entered a strange unicode character or something.  I can't paste what you've shown and get the same thing.

Comment: @Michael  I  added to my question.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you entered `\.00`, which matches the syntax for a character specified by hexadecimal character code. In this case, it's the null character (NUL; character code 0).

From [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#16741):

> ∖[Name] - a character with the specified full name
> ∖nnn - a character with octal code nnn
> **∖.nn - a character with hexadecimal code nn**
> ∖:nnnn - a character with hexadecimal code nnnn
> ∖|nnnnnn - a character with hexadecimal code nnnnnn

Comment: The experiment I described above indicates that if you ever type these four characters together in this order (\.00), then Mathematica automatically makes the substitution of a blank space.  I'm not sure how I ever made the mistake of putting those four characters down like that.   I would suggest that this substitution should not be so  automatic, because it hides your misstake.

Comment: @Chris Mathematica is not substituting a blank space; it's converting the escape sequence for a NUL character into a NUL character, which happens to look the same as a blank space. I think the fact that this conversion is automatic is rather the point. I might agree with a suggestion that certain unprintable characters, such as NUL, be rendered in a visible form like they are in some text editors.